# Smallest set of multi-sets that together contains all numbers from 1 to N

Tags: algorithm

Lets assume that we have only integer numbers which values are in range `1` to `N`. Next we will split them into `K-element` multi-sets. How would you find such set which contains smallest possible number of those multi-sets yet sum of this multi-set contains all numbers from `1` to `N`? In case of ambiguity answer will be any set that matches criteria (first found).

For instance, we have `N = 9`, `K = 3`

`(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,8)(8,7,6)(1,9,2)(4,4,3)`

Smallest number of multi-sets that contains all the numbers from `1` to `9` is equal to `4` and can be either `(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,8)(1,9,2)` or `(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(8,7,6)(1,9,2)`.

Any idea for efficient algorithm to find such set?

PS
After writing an answer I found yet another `4` element set: `(4,5,6)(1,9,2)(4,4,3)(7,8,8)` or `(4,5,6)(1,9,2)(4,4,3)(8,7,6)` But as I said algorithm finding any minimum set would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a restricted version the classic [Set Covering problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), but it still easy to show that it is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

Any approximation technique for this problem would be reasonable here. In particular, the [greedy solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm) of choosing the next subset covering the most uncovered items - is esp. easy to implement.

Comment: Oh thanks for the link. Actually my data are "quite small" N < 64 and number of sets cannot be grater than 500, so I guess I will try that linear programming approach which is on wikipedia. +1 and accept.

Answer (score 1):

This problem, as @Ami Tavroy said, is NP-hard by reduction to [3-dimensional matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) ([here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28363/set-cover-problem-with-constant-size-subset)).

To do the reduction, note the restricted decision variant of 3-dimensional matching when it reduces to a exact cover ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching#Decision_problem)):

> ...given a set T and an integer k, decide whether there exists a
>   3-dimensional matching M ⊆ T with |M| ≥ k. ... The problem is
>   NP-complete even in the special case that k = |X| = |Y| =
>   |Z|.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching)[4][5] In this case, a 3-dimensional (dominating) matching is
>   not only a set packing but also an exact cover: the set M covers each
>   element of X, Y, and Z exactly once.[6]

This variant can be solved in P if you can solve the other question in P - you can produce all the triples in `O(N ^ 3)` time and then do set cover, and check if `K = N / 3` or not. Thus by reduction, the original questions is also NP-hard.

Comment: *+e^0* (getting around SO's comment policy) for writing a precise reduction.